# KDE Plasma. Basically.. desktop is missing

Tags: kde, 19.10

I'm not sure when it started happening, but at a certain point, whenever I'd log into plasma desktop, the desktop background would be completely covered in a shape colored differently depending on the colour scheme, though the icons were still in-place.

The right click menu is different too. On my second screen, there is still a 2-3px gap, so I can access the desktop, but if I click on the shape on the primary monitor, it's back to the state it was in.

If I check

> Use desktop layout from theme

when applying a global theme, I can see my desktop again, but only until the next reboot.

[image: Problem:]

Comment: Did you try reinstalling the desktop?

Comment: yes i did and it didn't help but in the end i had to reinstall the os anyway, for reasons.. so the problem is not present anymore and i'm taking a wild guess here but most likely i had some component of gnome desktop in autostart back then.

Answer (score 0):

KDE desktop and panel and icons all missisng. A black screen.

Finally, running the below command, all came to live.

```
sudo plasma_session
```